# How to stop acpid restarting /etc/acpi/lid.sh restart unnecessarily?

Tags: acpi

On my Acer Aspire One netbook, I have noticed that acpid starts /etc/acpi/lid.sh multiple times a minute. This script should only be started when the lid is closed or opened. How can I stop theses unnecessary starts from happening without switching off acpi or disabling the lid event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the same issue as [this bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10485#c4)

If so there is a [description of the cause here](http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/acpi/continuous-acpi-lid-events-and-100-cpu-usage.html) and the [solution is here](http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/acpi/custom-dsdt.html)

Like the man says

> [this] involves recompiling the
>   kernel. Don't do this unless you're
>   familiar with the process. Back up
>   your machine beforehand. Follow this
>   guide at your own risk. Etc, etc

Comment: sounds quite similar. Unfortunately it looks like a BIOS bug, so applying the patch would nor really help since it would have to be done with every kernel update.

Comment: Or poke an Ubuntu kernel developer until they add it to the Ubuntu patch-set. Might need a bit more work to stop it attacking other systems (I haven't looked at the code) but otherwise, it's not hard to patch the Ubuntu kernel... Just takes a bit of time to compile.